# Javascript fails intermittently but works when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I have javascript to display and hide various parts of my page:

```
function showCustomer(str) {
    // remove white space from the name entered on the search screen
    str = str.replace(" ", "%20");
    var xmlhttp;

    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "No records found";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_customer.asp?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function enable_submit() {
    document.getElementById("id_simplesearch_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("autocomplete-search").reset();
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function disable_submit() {
    document.getElementById("id_simplesearch_submit").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("id_simplesearch").reset();
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "none";
}
```

I have a textbox with an

```
onkeyup="showCustomer(this.value)"
```

and an

```
onfocus="disable_submit()"
```

and a form defined as

```
    <div class="commandspace">
    <form id="id_simplesearch" name="simplesearch" method="post" action="index.asp">
    <div class="simplesearch"><label for="forename">Forename</label><input type="text" id="id_forename" name="forename" onfocus="enable_submit()" /></div>

    <div class="simplesearch"><label for="surname">Surname</label><input type="text" id="id_surname" name="surname" onfocus="enable_submit()" /></div>
    <div class="simplesearch"><label for="unit">Unit/Team</label><input type="text" id="id_unit" name="unit" onfocus="enable_submit()" /></div>

    <div id="simplesearchsubmit">
    <div class="simplesearch">
    <input class="simplesearchsubmit" type="submit" id="id_simplesearch_submit" name="search" value="Search" />
```

When you first load the page and start typing in the showCustomer search box, the txtHint element displays and begins pulling data back. If, however, I click into one of the three simplesearch boxes and then click back into the showCustomer search box, txtHint does not display at all.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out, what exactly is the problem here. Is `showCustomer` not working after the input is blurred? Or is `txtHint` not properly showing. Could you edit your post, so it becomes a little clearer?

Comment: Is that any clearer?

Comment: Yes, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here (see comments for the answer):

```
function enable_submit() {
    document.getElementById("id_simplesearch_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("autocomplete-search").reset();
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "none"; // <----- This uses display
    document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function disable_submit() {
    document.getElementById("id_simplesearch_submit").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("id_simplesearch").reset();
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.visibility = "visible"; // <----- This uses visibility
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display = "block"; // <----- This line should fix your problems.
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "none";
}
```

So `enable_submit` hides the element using display. While `disable_submit` tries to show it using visibility. The two style properties are mismatched.